# gulp.dest does not print to file

Tags: javascript, gulp

Hello I am having issues with gulp. Code bellow does not create anything in dist/ folder

```
function compileSources() {
    return gulp.src([ './src/**/*.js' ], {
        read: false
    })
    .pipe(debug())
  /*.pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(debug())*/
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
} 
gulp.task('compile-sources', compileSources);
```

Debug outputs

```
[10:56:45] Using gulpfile ~/otb-web-app/gulpfile.js
[10:56:45] Starting 'compile-sources'...
[10:56:45] gulp-debug: src/app.js
[10:56:45] gulp-debug: 1 item
[10:56:45] Finished 'compile-sources' after 28 ms
```

But in /dist folder nothing is created. Why could that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is this line `read: false` as an option on your gulp.src. Instead do something like:

```
gulp.src('./src/**/*.js')
  .pipe(debug())
  .pipe(concat('all.js'))
  .pipe(debug())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
```

Also as you are only defining one path in your `gulp.src` there's no need to use an array `[]`.

Comment: Yes, I have found that this is an issue... I was just writing my own answer but you were faster! thanks!